# Saving employee hierarchy PHP

Tags: php

I am creating a system that encodes the employee as well as his/her subordinate and superiors. This will be the basis of approvals inside the system.

For example:

1. If the user encodes the subordinates of an employee, all of those assigned employees will be its superior and vice versa if the user encodes the superior of an employee, the superior will be assigned a subordinate.

- Example 1, The user encodes the subordinate of Employee 1 which is Employee 2 and 3. Employee 2 and 3's superior will automatically be Employee 1
- Example 2 The use encodes the superior of Employee 2 and 3 which is Employee 1. Employee 1's subordinate now be Employee 2 and Employee 3 automatically.

2. If the user removes a subordinate of an employee, the employee's superior will be removed and vice versa if the user removes the superior of an employee. the employee with the subordinate will be removed.

- Example 1, The user removes subordinates of Employee 1 which is Employee 2 and 3. Employee 2 and 3's superior will be removed.
- Example 2, The use removes the superior of Employee 2 and 3 which is Employee 1. Employee 2 and 3 will be removed to Employee 1's subordinate.

I have this 2 tables that stores the subordinate and superior of an employee.

```
CREATE TABLE tblemployeesuperior (
   EMPLOYEE_ID VARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY,
   SUPERIOR_ID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   RECORD_LOG VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE tblemployeesubordinate (
   EMPLOYEE_ID VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   SUBORDINATE_ID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   RECORD_LOG VARCHAR(100)
);
```

Here is my code so far,

```
 if(!empty($superior)){
                    $delete_employee_superior = $api->delete_employee_superior($employee_id, $username);

                    if($delete_employee_superior == '1'){
                        $delete_employee_subordinate = $api->delete_employee_subordinate($employee_id, $username);

                        if($delete_employee_subordinate == '1'){
                            $insert_employee_superior = $api->insert_employee_superior($employee_id, $superior, $username);

                            if($insert_employee_superior == '1'){
                                $insert_employee_subordinate = $api->insert_employee_subordinate($superior, $employee_id, $username);

                                if($insert_employee_subordinate != '1'){
                                    $error = $insert_employee_subordinate;
                                }
                            }
                            else{
                                $error = $insert_employee_superior;
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            $error = $delete_employee_subordinate;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        $error = $delete_employee_superior;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    $delete_employee_superior = $api->delete_employee_superior($employee_id, $username);

                    if($delete_employee_superior == '1'){
                        $delete_employee_subordinate = $api->delete_employee_subordinate($employee_id, $username);

                        if($delete_employee_subordinate != '1'){
                            $error = $delete_employee_subordinate;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(!empty($subordinates)){
                    $subordinates = explode(',', $subordinates);

                    $delete_all_employee_subordinate = $api->delete_all_employee_subordinate($employee_id, $username);

                    if($delete_all_employee_subordinate == '1'){
                        foreach($subordinates as $subordinate){
                            $insert_employee_subordinate = $api->insert_employee_subordinate($employee_id, $subordinate, $username);

                            if($insert_employee_subordinate == '1'){
                                $delete_employee_superior = $api->delete_employee_superior($subordinate, $username);

                                if($delete_employee_superior == '1'){
                                    $insert_employee_superior = $api->insert_employee_superior($subordinate, $employee_id, $username);

                                    if($insert_employee_superior != '1'){
                                        $error = $insert_employee_superior;
                                    }
                                }
                                else{
                                    $error = $delete_employee_superior;
                                }
                            }
                            else{
                                $error = $insert_employee_subordinate;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        $error = $delete_all_employee_subordinate;
                    }
                }
```

I am having problems with assigning and re-assigning of superior and subordinates with my code. Is there a way to improve this?

Comment: _Is there a way to improve this?_ Get ride of this enormous if else structure.. Consider using a switch case. Also convert your strings to integer/boolean, so you don't have to check on '1' but just check on the variable. On the actual logic, this is now too complex to understand what is exactly happening.

Comment: @Wimanicesir noted, thank you my problem is the logic on how can I solve the examples above

Comment: Does the code you have work and just need "improving", or is it not working? If it's working, I'd be tempted to leave well alone. If not, forget about the language for a minute and draw a flowchart to cover every eventuality, then code it. It's very difficult to figure out what by me right or wrong with the code posted as we don't know what the variables and functions actually do. Slightly o/t but why are your `id` fields all varchar instead of numeric?